# How to use selenium 4.11.2v for scraping in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox, geckodriver

I have used older selenium versions with geckodriver in python to scrap data. But now i have to use selenium 11.4.2v with firefox 113v. In this version the geckodriver path is not necessary to define. I have not any idea about other changes to related that version.

I have build the following code snippet and want to know changes should be done within the code.

```
import bs4
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

self.options = Options()self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
self.options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
if os.environ.get('IS_SERVER') == "1":
self.profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
self.profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
self.profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
self.profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
# self.options.add_argument('--headless')
self.options.headless = True

def my_driver(self):
try:
self.helper.check_connection()
# self.tor_handler.renew_connection()
options = FirefoxOptions()
self.profile.update_preferences()
firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
webdriver_wait = WebDriverWait(firefox_driver, 25, poll_frequency=1)
firefox_driver.set_page_load_timeout(200)
return True, firefox_driver, webdriver_wait
except:
traceback.print_exc()
return False
```